# "Please consider adding a comment" obscures the "Add comment" link

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface

If the answer you're voting down is short, the message that asks you to add a comment obscures the very link that lets you do that. Given that this message cannot even be clicked away, the overall experience is a little frustrating.

IMO the best way to fix this is to let me click the message to close it, but I believe this idea is not very popular for some reason.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Downvote more often :)

Comment: Please explain :) I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Gain enough rep and the prompt will go away.

Comment: For me - yes. For 99.9% other users who don't have enough rep it will remain.

Comment: "Gain enough rep" is a pretty idiotic response to a bugreport that affects all people with little rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must only happen on short messages/answers/questions because once the content is bigger than about 100 pixels, the box does not cover it up.

At any rate, the box can be clicked to make it go away or you can just wait for the timeout.

Comment: It cannot (just tested it here again), and this answer is short enough to be susceptible too.

Comment: "It cannot" ? What do you mean? Can you click to make it go away?

Comment: No, I cannot click it to make it go away. As in, I can click it, but it won't go away. There is no "click to dismiss" message in it either.

Comment: It can be clicked now. It didn't use to be.